# How do you add a repeated sine wave distortion to a curve for 3d printing?

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing, sverchok

There is a variety of 3D printers online who apply a sine wave function to the gcode path in blender and rhino/grasshopper that creates a very interesting effect on a 3d printed model. When you import a model into blender, you can slice it into printable layers with tissue and can do some minor manipulation, however to get a consistent sine wave...i'm a little lost. I think you would use geometry nodes and scaling in the x and y axis but I'm lost after that. Any ideas?

here is a good example where the gif was actually also rendered in blender:
https://twitter.com/tnctrekit/status/1482906930758651907?s=20&t=ibYqjaO9CFS29ykF0TbC7A

Answer (score 6):

with this node setup you can get a sin distortion on your curve:

[image]

The "normal/xy" expands the sine on the normal or just flat on xy plane.

result:

[image]

Comment: It is version 3.2. if my answer helped u, please click on the checkmark left of my answer

Comment: I'm sorry I am very new to this, how do I add the point along the curve, when I adjust the wave height and whatnot the whole curve just gets smaller not in a sine pattern. Also, Where do I actually input my curve into the nodes If I'm working with something other than the spiral in the example you gave?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WlXu7Pi

here is what I have so far you can see in the gif the problem I'm having

Answer (score 0):

Here is example in sverchok, how i doing that. Reparametrise with curve object and work with adaptive edge node.
gist to import:
https://gist.github.com/4df5dc4c55524dc852a5673766349ec3

[image: sverchok spiral example]

Answer (score 0):

This is one node setup that achieves something similar. In this setup I chose to use the bend object along path node. [image: bend-on-path-setup]